# Jenkins Archive Downstream Multibranch Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifact

I have a multibranch pipeline in Jenkins and need to pass the archive from the pipeline to a job it builds. The copy artifact plugin doesnt seem to support multibranch pipelines. It deletes my source project every time I save. Is there another plugin I can use to get the archive to get passed to the job? Or is there something I need to do to get this plugin working with multibranch pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The copy artifact plugin doesnt seem to support multibranch pipelines.

Copy Artifact does not care about multibranch. From its perspective, a branch project is simply a job that is in some folder. And it does support folders. You just need to use the correct syntax for the source job. Last I remember, it supports either relative (e.g., `../multibranch/master`) or absolute (e.g., `/organization/repo/master`).

Comment: Thanks, I added a parameter for the build job for the project name of the upstream project and now it is working.